# Genereic de-serialization method in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have this method to Serialize an object with any type

```
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
```

Now I need some method to deserialize string into object type which I can cast depends on some code.

My question is how this method could be implemented?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I don't thing the generics are doing much for you there, if you remove t entirely made toSerialize of type object and called `New XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType())` you would get the same end result i think.

Comment: to @Ian Evil is always near... ;) Hahahah I do it bro!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlDataToDeSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlDeSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlDataToeSerialize);
    return (T)xmlDeSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);            
}
```